# SQL Update with KEY FIELDS, but not changing they value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table on MS SQL, say - TAB1 with key fields KEY1 and KEY2 and a value field COLUMN1.

It has a row with values:
    KEY1 = A;
    KEY2 = B;
    COLUMN1 = 123;

I want to fire this SQL update:

```
UPDATE TAB1
SET    KEY1 = A,
       KEY2 = B,
       COLUMN1 = 999
WHERE  KEY1 = A
       AND KEY2 = B
```

I know that the right SQL Update statement will be:

```
UPDATE TAB1
SET    COLUMN1 = 999
WHERE  KEY1 = A
       AND KEY2 = B
```

But still... Will it somehow affect update speed, indexes, etc. 
Or MS SQL clever enough to deal with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at actual execution plans? If there's no difference, performance will be the same

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don not have an access to MS SQL Server itself - I'm just executing this statement from my application...

Comment: Maybe create a test environment with test data where you do have access. SQL Express is free!

Comment: Is this even a real question?

Comment: @ChrisBednarski - That isn't necessarily the case as things like logging don't show up in execution plans. In this case the change to `COLUMN1` will need to be logged any way. [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx) discusses some relevant cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand in which case it make sense to use the first query instead of the second query...

You'll probably not have a noticeable performance difference between both queries but if you have index on these columns, the update process may have an impact on it and cause some additional execution time (i'm not an expert on indexes but on every `INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE` on an indexed column, the modifications have an impact on the concerned index. May be not a big impact if you update with the same value but SQL Server will not be aware of that until a check is made between the values...).

I suggest you to use the second approach if possible, you'll have a more readable query and be sure to avoid misunderstanding when you need to come back few months later to work on your code ;-)

As i said, i'm not an expert but in my opinion it's a best practice to keep it simple when possible.

Hope this will help you.